# Is my question a bad fit for SO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, migration

I've asked a [question about parallelization optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814108/parallel-framework-and-avoiding-false-sharing) using .NET's Parallel Framework, because I had learned about a topic (false-sharing) in an attempt to answer a different question on parallelization.

There's been noted some concern about if this is off-topic or not, and it's got a close vote for being too broad. One suggestion was to post it on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Reviewing its Help Center, I believe this to be on-topic for both, but I'm naturally biased as it's my question. They may have a point though - after all the question that spawned mine had similar concerns in comments.

Thoughts?

Comment: I answer a lot of optimization questions but this one is just too fake.  The odds that it generates a usable insight that valuable to multiple programmers are too low.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there a point to generalizing it to "how to better optimize some set of arbitrary operations"? I know that computing all permutations of arbitrary base numbers is definitely not a real problem (that I can think of...)

Comment: Not that I can think of.

Comment: Your question is far too broad for this site. SO is for *specific questions about actual problems you are facing*, and (unless you're working on a homework assignment that requires it), "how to better optimize some set of arbitrary operations* is not in any way *specific*.

Comment: @jdphenix Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @JaredBurrows More or less. My scenario was a contrived example which I successfully optimized to what I believe to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Your question seems to be a little "*Too Broad*", you already have 3 close votes for being too broad. I would consider editing the question and making it more specific; however, someone may come along and answer soon!

### First:

When in doubt, always refer back to the **StackOverflow** help pages: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

### Second:

I believe your main concern is: *"Is my question on topic for **StackOverflow**?"*

> 1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>    shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>    Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>    readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>    example.

You are not asking for someone to find an error with your code.

> 2. Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions
>    may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to
>    help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and
>    closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the
>    problem before posting.

Possibly but you are not asking for fixing a bug in which someone would try to reproduce. You are asking for possibly ways of optimization.

> 3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the
>    difficulty you are having solving it.

No.

> 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>    Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>    Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>    it.

No, your question was related to

> 5. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used
>    primarily for programming.

No, your question topic is related to optimization of code.

> 6. Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless
>    they directly involve programming or programming tools.

No, your question topic is related to optimization of code.

#### Other Criteria:

> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s
> also OK to ask and answer your own question. Questions which are too
> broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be put on
> hold by the community until they are improved.

I listed them here:

> 1. Too broad

### This maybe there only one. As you can see you have 3 close votes for this already.

> 2. Unclear

I believe you question extremely clear with plenty of details.

> 3. Incomplete

I believe you question extremely clear with plenty of details.

> 4. Opinion-based

Not really, just looking for different ways to optimize.

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic